# Передача данных в инстанс Vue извне

Tags: javascript, vue.js

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <my-component></my-component>
</div>
<script>
function asyncFunction () {

}
</script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import MyComponent from './components/MyComponent.vue'

new Vue({ 
  el: '#app',
  components: { MyComponent }
})
```

MyComponent.vue

```
export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',
  data () {
    return {
      session: ''
    }
  }
}
```

Вопрос в том, как из `asyncFunction` передать в компонент (или в корневой элемент) какие-либо данные, чтобы после этого произошел перерендеринг компонента `MyComponent`.

Для приведенного выше примера нужно обновить свойство `session` в компоненте `MyComponent` после вызова `asyncFunction`.

Comment: А почему это не делать в самом компоненте ?

Comment: @MoJlo4HuK Потому что `asyncFunction` вызывается не мной, хотя ее код пишу я. Считайте, что ее вызов гарантированно произойдет, но когда это случится заранее неизвестно. В этот момент и надо обновить данные на экране.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.App = new Vue({....})
function asyncFunction () {
    window.App.session = 'Yeah'
}
```